# Changing plane on Azure it shows: HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure (Windows Server)

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I m using abp (Aspnet boilerplate) with net core 2.2.0 .

The backend run without problems in local and also in Azure with the D1 plane.

But if i change plane to B1 or higher, it shows this error:

[image]

Why? The code is the same. i ve changed only the subscription plane. There are many similar questions online but no answer solves my problem.

**EDIT**

If I pusblish from Visual Studio it works but if i publish through Continuous integration (through the azure pipelines) the problem returns

My yml:

```
    trigger:
- dev

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use dotnet sdk 2.2'
  inputs:
    version: 2.x
    includePreviewVersions: false

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

# code coverage
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect "Code coverage"'

# - script: dotnet test <test-project> --logger trx --collect "Code coverage"
# - task: PublishTestResults@2
#   inputs:
#     testRunner: VSTest
#     testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'

- script: dotnet -d ef -v migrations script --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\SQL\$(scriptName) --context $(dbContext)  --idempotent --project src\WorkFlowManager.EntityFrameworkCore\WorkFlowManager.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

Comment: Do you use Azure web app service? Could you please tell me which part you have published to the Azure? Webhost or WebMVC or else. Besides, I suggest you could enable the details logs or application inslights to see the details error message about the 502.5 issue.

Comment: Yes, i use Azure web app service and i have published only the APIs. Now if i pusblish from Visual Studio it works but if i publish through Continuous integration (through the azure pipelines) the problem returns